# Turning ON and OFF LEDs in Arduino based on color recognition in OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, arduino

I need to turn on and off LEDs with Arduino through Python and OpenCV. If I load an image with a red color, a red LED has to turn on, and so on for three other colors. I already have a code that detects the red color and deletes the rest of the image, and a 'while' structure that turns off and on a LED each milisecond. However, I don't know how to save the TRUE state from getting the red color and then programming an ''if'' condition to control the LED. Thanks in advance.

```
import pyfirmata2
import cv2 as cv #libreria de opencv
import numpy as np #libreria de numpy

original = cv.imread('C:/Users/admin/Documents/Personales/circles.png')
DELAY = 1
PORT = pyfirmata2.Arduino.AUTODETECT
board = pyfirmata2.Arduino(PORT)

rb1 = np.array([0,100,20],np.uint8)
ra1 = np.array([8,255,255],np.uint8)
rb2 = np.array([175,100,20],np.uint8)
ra2 = np.array([179,255,255],np.uint8)

imgHSV = cv.cvtColor(original,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mr1 = cv.inRange(imgHSV,rb1,ra1)
mr2 = cv.inRange(imgHSV,rb2,ra2)

mascaraRoja = cv.add(mr1,mr2)
mascaraFinal = cv.bitwise_and(original, original, mask = mascaraRoja)

cv.imshow('Original',original)
cv.imshow('Filtrada',mascaraFinal)
while True:
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    board.pass_time(DELAY)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    board.pass_time(DELAY)
cv.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general observations...

- Put comments in your code
- Move the `waitKey()` to immediately after `imshow()`, else it will never run (because there's an infinite loop after it) and that means the images won't be drawn on your screen
- Remove the loop at the end - you only need to turn the LED on or off once
- Use `cv.countNonZero()` to count the number of pixels in your mask and save it in a variable, e.g. `nRed = cv.countNonZero(...mask...)`
- Add an `if` statement at the end that checks to see if LED must be switched on or off

Like this:

```
if nRed > 0:
    board.digital[13].write(1)
else:
    board.digital[13].write(0)
```

---

Finally, this one is a bit more esoteric. Hue is an angle that runs from 0..179 and Red happens to straddle the range with values of 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 0, 1, 2 ... 8. That means you need to test twice and combine masks. Instead of that, you can invert the image and look for Cyan which is then contiguous and centred on 90:

```
mask = cv.inRange(~imgHSV, ...)
```

with low limit 83 and high limit 97.